# Can't add CSS to rails class

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have this rails link-to button which isn't stylized with css and i dont know why.

```
<%= link_to "Home", {controller: "public", action: "index"}, class: "mainmenu" %>
```

And the CSS which is'nt doing anything:

```
.mainmenu {


float: left;
height: 500px;
width: 100px;
margin-right: 5px;
background-image: black;
text-align: center;
line-height: 50px;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Do you have a target class in generated link?

Comment: What do you mean about target class? sorry

Comment: You should view your output html and figure out is there present target class for that link

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
<%= link_to "Home", controller: "public", action: "index", class: "mainmenu" %>
```

Comment: Does not make changes to button stylization, but it makes the link http://localhost:3000/?class=mainmenu

Comment: Can you explain a bit about the code you've posted? It might help OP or future users more.

Comment: The link-to button code i've putted in views/layouts/loggedin and the problem was that the css did not recognized this link-to button because it was in the layout file. And i used in the controllers layout to show this loggedin layout. So now i made new controller named public with few actions like home. And then i putted that link-to code under views/public/home where the css works now. Happy but now with my english.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<%= link_to "Home", publics_path, class: "mainmenu" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of different things that could be wrong here. Here's what I'd start with:

1. In your rendered HTML, can you confirm that your "Home" link has a `class` attribute with `mainmenu` as it's value? If so, then the issue is not in the generation of the link, so move on to step 2.
2. In the CSS that's loaded on the page, can you confirm that `mainmenu` is indeed present and contains the properties that you expect? If not, then the issue is that the CSS is simply not being loaded.